# How to send a request using socket and check status code?

Tags: python, sockets

So I am very new to Python and am now trying to understand how to send a request using TCP in Python. The sample code and document is not very helpful (to me, as I don't understand Java).

The document:

https://www.sharekhan.com/Upload/General/TradeTigerAPIForClient.pdf

I have the following till now

```
import socket

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server = '192.168.43.211'
port = 800

request = "DataLength = 196|Transcode = 1|LoginId = ***|MemberPassword = sh*|TradingPassword = S77*| IP = 192.618.31.211|Reserved = |"

s.connect((server,port))
s.send(request.encode())
result = s.recv(4096)
```

If I use this the program shows I am connected and the `result` is `b''`

I also tried

`request = "|DataLength =108|Transcode = 21|Exchange Code=NC|Reserved=|"`

`result` is `b'Hurray you are connected'`

How do I use the commands from the document to get data?

Comment: Your IP address is bogus. 618 is not a valid octet (the range is 0-255). You probably meant 192.*168*.31.211. But in any case, a 192.168.x.x address is reserved for private networks and hence is meaningless beyond your local router. ...

Comment: That document seems to explain a binary protocol. I think you will need to binary encode the fields. For example, data length is defined as `LONG` (a 4-byte signed integer). They don't give the byte ordering so you will have to guess (or look at what the java code is doing). The field names they show in the examples are inconsistent with the defining tables but in binary that won't matter (as long as you can determine the datum needed). That document is pretty lame for a protocol specification. Anyway, to create binary encodings, you will want to use python's `struct` module.

Comment: @GilHamilton the document is very frustrating, the sample code they have provided is in java/C# which I can't comprehend(started with python and pretty much have no idea which file under the sample folders to check). The ip I changed back to what it shows in my system.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/sockets.html), you can send a TCP packet like this:

```
import socket

server = '192.168.31.211'
port = 80
buffer_size = 4096

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((server, port))
sock.send(message)
data = sock.recv(buffer_size)
sock.close()
```

Note I didn't include your message here, nor did I encode your data. However, as was pointed out in the comments, your IP address is incorrectly written and refers to a private IP address, according to the [IANA](https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-a-private-ip-address-2625970) so if you're trying to send out over a public network, this won't work. Additionally, I have noticed a couple of other problems with your code:

1. Your message looks like you've manually included TCP header information. Be aware that by using the `socket` library the way you are and the way I have suggested, you are making a TCP request. The header information will therefore be included with your request so you don't need to include it yourself.
2. What you have here is the client code and you didn't include any server code. Have you written code for your server? If not, you'll need some.

Otherwise, I can't see any problems with your code.

Comment: Thanks. The server side is provided by the broker. I am wondering if the `request` I am making is in the correct format, as per docs/link above. If I understand correctly I just need to send:`LoginId = ***|MemberPassword = sh*|TradingPassword = S77*`?

Comment: @Sid That depends on what your server expects. I was just pointing out what looked like TCP headers in your message.The fact that you received `b''` implies that your connection did not go through as planned. My guess is that your IP address was wrong. You should try connecting over the public IP